# How to integrate different templates for my frontend and backend pages of my website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

Could anyone please help me with this situation.

I do have a front-end and a back-end for my website.The problem that i encounter here is that i have 2  specific templates ,one for the front-end and other for the back-end.I have integrated my front-end design using the page.tpl.php file.But how am i supposed to integrate my back-end template on to my site.A little help would be very useful.

Comment: by backend, do you mean all admin/* pages or it is something else ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a theme for the admin interface. Go to

```
admin/appearance
```

At the bottom of the page you should see a drop down menu to select your admin theme.